# android code to make calls from a voice input

Tags: android

Can anybody help me to set up a voice dialer, which will detect the voice of the user and if the user is saying a number then the number should be dialed automatically

Answer (score 1):

I would post this in a comment, but I don't have a high enough reputation. I also don't know how much background information you have; my post might not be helpful at all.

Do you have the recognizer intent implemented?

- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognizerIntent.html

If not, the following looks like it could help you get started

- http://www.jameselsey.co.uk/blogs/techblog/android-how-to-implement-voice-recognition-a-nice-easy-tutorial

From my simple view of this, you could take the data from that and parse the numbers from it. I would be interested in hearing from somebody with more experience with this, though.